# How to select different plist files from menu

Tags: ios, streaming

I built an iOS App to play videos through a plist file. I want to make an options button or menu to select different plist files. Each plist file will have a different category. I'm new to iOS and I've searched everywhere for an answer, but with out any luck.

Here is where I define where my plist file exists.

```
define URL DATA @"file.plist"
```

How would I change this to possibly look at a plist file that contains the URL of each plist file so I can switch them by a click of a menu button?

Comment: Are you going to add static or dynamic plist?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I will have a plist file located on a webserver which will allow me to add content. I would like a different plist file per category, and will eventually attempt to make a slideout menu which will allow you to select a category, with that selection I would like this line to point to that selection. For example, If you select category #1 - #define URL Data @:http://category1.plist", and each category would have its own plist located on my server. My app is working properly, just want to add the ability to select more than one plist now. Thanks